# I can curl another docker container inside docker compose but not fetch in code

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, create-react-app

I can't fetch from `server container` to `frontend container`  even though I am able to get `curl` response from inside `frontend container`.

I have a docker-compose set up with a frontend and server container.
I want to fetch server response from frontend, but i get the error `GET http://server:5000/api/panels net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`. I get the correct response if i execute the following command from inside the frontend container `curl http://server:5000/api/panels`

Dockerfile server

```
FROM node:11
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "node", "server" ]
```

Dockerfile frontend

```
FROM node:11
ADD . /frontend
WORKDIR /frontend
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  server:
    build: .

  frontend:
    depends_on:
      - server
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "3030:3000"
```

api-call

```
this.callApi()
      .then((res: ISolarPanels) => {
        this.setState({ solarPanels: res })
      })
      .catch((err) => console.warn('server is offline?', err))

 private callApi = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_URL+'/api/panels')
    const body = await response.json()\
    if (response.status !== 200) {
      throw Error(body.message)
    }
    return body
  }
```

package.json (i use `dev` script for local development and `start` for docker

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/d3": "^5.0.1",
    "d3": "^5.7.0",
    "prettier": "^1.13.5",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-scripts-ts": "2.16.0",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "^5.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "node_modules/.bin/tslint -c tslint.json 'src/**/{*.ts,*.tsx}'",
    "dev": "REACT_APP_URL=http://localhost:3000 react-scripts-ts start",
    "start": "REACT_APP_URL=http://server:5000 react-scripts-ts start",
    "build": "react-scripts-ts build",
    "test": "react-scripts-ts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts-ts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^10.3.3",
    "@types/react": "^16.3.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.6",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your host url?

Comment: right now, its only localhost. The frontend is `localhost:3030`

Comment: The error may come because of many issues. It usually indicates that the domain name cannot be resolved. It may also come because of your firewall restrictions.

Comment: Could you please try it by hitting on 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost?

Comment: I get the same error from the frontend on `0.0.0.0:3030` and `localhost:3030`.

Comment: whats the output of console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_URL)

Comment: It is `http://server:5000`

Comment: Im currently investigating a possible solution. The reason the request is not going through is that my browser is not in the same network as the server container, and therefore cannot reach it. I think I will have to look at proxy to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a quick fix, you can allow `CORS` on your server. [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

And in your web application you can use:
`0.0.0.0:5000/api` for pointing to server.

Also, you would need to bind your port in `server` service in docker-compose.yml file.

```
  server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

Answer (score 1):

**To sum up what went wrong and how it was fixed**. 
The request was of-course sendt from the browser, and not the frontend container, therefore the server port needed to be exposed and CORS enabled from the serverside.